# Pass data depending on Column and Row

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to transfer a 1 or 0 from one sheet "5s Audit" to another sheet "Feb Aisle Score" Depending on a pass or fail that would execute with a Submit button , the thing is that the location I need the pass or fail to transfer over to would be specific Cell Depending on Date or Area as shown on the Image(**Date/Area**) which are Drop Down Lists.

[Sheet1 Date / Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2jaf.png)

The Sheet that would need the Data Passed down to is Fixed up to have the Date (which is a digit for every day of the month 1-31) as the Columns and The Area as the Row. As shown Below.

[Sheet2 Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt0cu.png)

What I have tried to do was to see if i could use a Dim Statement to start it off but I Cant for the life of me figure out in which way to refer to the Area as Row and Date as Column.

I have already set all Area Cells starting from "Dim Loc1 As String" and the Days starting "Dim Day1 As Double" and referred to each Cell Location including the first 2 Criteria in Sheet 1 ".

```html
Sub Submit_Button()

Dim Loc1 As String
Dim Loc2 As String
Dim Loc3 As String
Dim Loc4 As String
Dim Loc5 As String
Dim Loc6 As String
Dim Loc7 As String
Dim Loc8 As String
Dim Loc9 As String
Dim Loc10 As String
Dim Loc11 As String
Dim Loc12 As String
Dim Loc13 As String
Dim Loc14 As String
Dim Loc15 As String
Dim Loc16 As String
Dim Loc17 As String
Dim Loc18 As String
Dim Loc19 As String
Dim Loc20 As String
Dim Loc21 As String
Dim Loc22 As String
Dim Loc23 As String
Dim Loc24 As String
Dim Loc25 As String
Dim Loc26 As String
Dim Loc27 As String
Dim Loc28 As String
Dim Loc29 As String
Dim Loc30 As String
Dim Loc31 As String
Dim Loc32 As String
Dim Loc33 As String
Dim Loc34 As String
Dim Loc35 As String
Dim Loc36 As String



Dim Day1 As Double
Dim Day2 As Double
Dim Day3 As Double
Dim Day4 As Double
Dim Day5 As Double
Dim Day6 As Double
Dim Day7 As Double
Dim Day8 As Double
Dim Day9 As Double
Dim Day10 As Double
Dim Day11 As Double
Dim Day12 As Double
Dim Day13 As Double
Dim Day14 As Double
Dim Day15 As Double
Dim Day16 As Double
Dim Day17 As Double
Dim Day18 As Double
Dim Day19 As Double
Dim Day20 As Double
Dim Day21 As Double
Dim Day22 As Double
Dim Day23 As Double
Dim Day24 As Double
Dim Day25 As Double
Dim Day26 As Double
Dim Day27 As Double
Dim Day28 As Double
Dim Day29 As Double
Dim Day30 As Double
Dim Day31 As Double





Dim day As Double
Dim auditor As String
Dim area As String
Dim passorfail As String




day = Sheets("5S Audit").Range("c10").Value
auditor = Sheets("5S Audit").Range("f10").Value
area = Sheets("5S Audit").Range("j10").Value
passorfail = Sheets("5S Audit").Range("p5").Value

'Aisle LOC
Loc1 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B4").Value
Loc2 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B5").Value
Loc3 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B6").Value
Loc4 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B7").Value
Loc5 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B8").Value
Loc6 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B9").Value
Loc7 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B10").Value
Loc8 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B11").Value
Loc9 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B12").Value
Loc10 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B13").Value
Loc11 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B14").Value
Loc12 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B15").Value
Loc13 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B16").Value
Loc14 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B17").Value
Loc15 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B18").Value
Loc16 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B19").Value
Loc17 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B20").Value
Loc18 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B21").Value
Loc19 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B22").Value
Loc20 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B23").Value
Loc21 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B24").Value
Loc22 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B25").Value
Loc23 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B26").Value
Loc24 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B27").Value
Loc25 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B28").Value
Loc26 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B29").Value
Loc27 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B30").Value
Loc28 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B31").Value
Loc29 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B32").Value
Loc30 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B33").Value
Loc31 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B34").Value
Loc32 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B35").Value
Loc33 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B36").Value
Loc34 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B37").Value
Loc35 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B38").Value
Loc36 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("B39").Value



'Days
Day1 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("C3").Value
Day2 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("D3").Value
Day3 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("E3").Value
Day4 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("F3").Value
Day5 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("G3").Value
Day6 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("H3").Value
Day7 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("I3").Value
Day8 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("J3").Value
Day9 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("K3").Value
Day10 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("L3").Value
Day11 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("M3").Value
Day12 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("N3").Value
Day13 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("O3").Value
Day14 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("P3").Value
Day15 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("Q3").Value
Day16 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("R3").Value
Day17 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("S3").Value
Day18 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("T3").Value
Day19 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("U3").Value
Day20 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("V3").Value
Day21 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("W3").Value
Day22 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("X3").Value
Day23 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("Y3").Value
Day24 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("Z3").Value
Day25 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AA3").Value
Day26 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AB3").Value
Day27 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AC3").Value
Day28 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AD3").Value
Day29 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AE3").Value
Day30 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AF3").Value
Day31 = Sheets("Feb Aisle Score").Range("AG3").Value


End Sub
```

The Help Would be Greatly Appreciated.

```html
Dim mydate As String, myaisle As String, myscore As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim coord1 As Integer, coord2 As Integer

mydate = Worksheets("5s Audit").Range("C10").Value
myaisle = Worksheets("5s Audit").Range("F10").Value
myscore = Worksheets("Score Transfer").Range("C1").Value

For i = 4 To 39
    If Worksheets("Score Transfer").Cells(i, 1).Value = myaisle Then
        coord1 = i
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To 32
    If Worksheets("Score Transfer").Cells(3, i).Value = mydate Then
        coord2 = i
    End If
Next i

Worksheets("Score Transfer").Cells(coord1, coord2).Value = myscore
```

EDIT: Added the code dwirony provided with My Spreadsheets Locations.

Comment: Hi Erick - it sounds like you've started trying to write something yourself. Could you please include that code snippet (before your question is closed?). Anything is better than nothing.

Comment: Thank You dwirony, i have added the code snippet of what i had started with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this can be done pretty simply by assigning your date and aisle values to variables, then just looking for them on your data sheet; I had to improvise the ranges because you didn't include them in your pictures - You'd have to retrofit this code to your needs.

```
Sub MoveOneorZero()

Dim mydate As String, myaisle As String, myscore As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim coord1 As Integer, coord2 As Integer

mydate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value
myaisle = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I3").Value
myscore = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H1").Value

For i = 4 To 22
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = myaisle Then
        coord1 = i
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To 32
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i).Value = mydate Then
        coord2 = i
    End If
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(coord1, coord2).Value = myscore

End Sub
```

Sheet1 Example:

[image: Sheet1 Example]

Sheet2 Example:

[[image: Sheet2 Example]]

After running macro:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvYeT.png)[[image: After running]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TruLU.png)

Comment: Thank You dwirony, sorry about not providing the information, would i be able to do the opposite using this same structure?  As in would i be able using a Command button to execute instead move the total score on your last image to the desired date and area  based off of the locations ?   

Example: Total Score = 1  and have that be filled into Date 9 for Area Aisle H 1st ?

Comment: @ErickU9314 Yes, I've edited the code (by changing the line near the end to `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(coord1, coord2).Value = myscore`)

Comment: i have made the changes you showed and affixed them to my sheet names but it seems to have an error on the last line which you provided me above, it gives the (Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error").

Comment: i have added snipet of your code with sheets names i have and fixed my spreadsheet like your shown in image 3 to match , so all fields match up with the Integers and Strings.

Comment: @ErickU9314 Something's not lined up correctly because either `coord1` or `coord2` were never found.

Comment: Thank You so much , as you said I found that i had Missed the Cell by 1 and that was the reason for the Erorr.   I would like to Thank You again dwirony for your help I Greatly Appreciate it.